# onMouseButtonUp

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent, mouse

I need some way to find out when the user released the mouse button - something like keyUp - but for the mouse...

Any ideas?

PS: I want to mimic: active pseudo-class and my idea was `to do something()` on `mouse press`, and `UnDoSomething()` on `mouse button up` ... now ... if you got a better solution - hit me up! :)

Comment: mousePress would be **onmousedown**... mouseButtonUp is **onmouseup**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event is `onmouseup`: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseup.asp

Or `mouseup` if you're calling element.addEventListener or using one of the JavaScript frameworks that drop the "on" part of the name.

**Update:**

If you want to listen for *any* mouse up event, you'll need to register an onmouseup listener on the page body in your onmousedown callback, and then unregister the onmouseup listener from within the onmouseup callback (so it only happens once).

If you're using jQuery, this can be accomplished with the [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function.

Of course, if the user moves their mouse outside of the browser window before releasing their button, you won't get the mouseup event. I'm not sure if there's anything you can do about that.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't work for me, because user can release mouse button away from element. 

mouseUp just works if you are above given element. I need to work something out.

Comment: I am making maximized window application - so basically I don't care out-of-the-window situations. 

Thanks - you have made some thing clear to me :)

Answer (score 1):

The according event is called onmouseup... You can see a sample implementation here:
http://www.webmonkey.com/codelibrary/JavaScript_Event_-_Mouseup

Answer (score 1):

What you might be looking for is something like:

```
<button onmouseup="alert('hello world');">Say hello world on mouse-up</button>
```